# Win 7 HP ProBook 4540s Press Esc key duration at boot

Tags: windows-7, boot

Model: Win 7 HP ProBook 4540s

Message: `Press Esc key duration at boot`
Can the time the message stays at the bottom right corner of the screen when Booting be controlled/ reduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because it stays there, during the boot. Like a progress-bar. You can't change the time.